# Chrome's offsetWidth inconsistent with FF/IE

Tags: html, dom

I Recently took over a project were the navigation menus were not displaying correctly. I narrowed the problem down to how chrome is calculating the offsetWidth for a parent `<a>` containing a child `<p>`. All other browsers would take the child into account when calculating the offsetWidth for the parent but chrome would give a width of 0. My solution was to set the outer tag to `display:block`.

This fiddle demonstrates the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZwNM/

What I want to know is why this is happening? Is this due to the fact of placing a `<p>` inside an `<a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find all the required information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level).

Just to quote relevant parts:

> When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box (and its inline ancestors within the same line box) are broken around the block-level box (and any block-level siblings that are consecutive or separated only by collapsible whitespace and/or out-of-flow elements), splitting the inline box into two boxes (even if either side is empty), one on each side of the block-level box(es). The line boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of those anonymous boxes. When such an inline box is affected by relative positioning, any resulting translation also affects the block-level box contained in the inline box.

So for example, if you add some `inline` contents within your `wrapper` (e.g. this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mishik/2ZwNM/2/)) then width of that `wrapper` will be the `width` of those inline contents.